# Django proxy admin

Tags: python, django, proxy, django-admin

I'm trying to create separated user for django admin, that has limited permissions instead of regular admin. I know that the best approach will be to use proxy admin, but I'm facing some problems.

I've got models structure, that is unlikely to be changed. Each model inherits from some abstract base model class. And I'm unable to add `proxy=True` clause. The structure of models looks more or less like that:

```
class AbstractObject(models.Model):
    @property
    def some_property_that_applies_to_each_child_model(self):
        pass

    class Meta():
        abstract = True

class ModelOne(AbstractObject):
    id_field = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    @property
    def some_custom_property(self):
        pass

class ModelTwo(AbstractObject):
    id_field = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    @property
    def some_other_custom_property(self):
        pass
```

now I want to create restricted admin account that can do only some actions that aren't deal with db. I know that I need to add `proxy=True` in `class Meta` definition for each model, but it isn't working... I get the error `raise typeerror(proxy model %s has no non-abstract model base class. % name)` which is quite obvious. Should I create some kind of non-abstract model base mock class and add it to the db tables?

I hope that you will get the idea of what I've encountered

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a proxy-Model of an abstract class. Your Proxy-Model need to inherit from a non-abstract Model. Try to use proxy this way:

```
class AbstractBaseModel(models.Model):
    #some code

    class Meta():
        abstract = True

class MyModel(AbstractBaseModel):
    #some code

class ProxyModel(MyModel):
    #some code

    class Meta:
        proxy=True
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to do it like this, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models):

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MyPerson(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def do_something(self):
        # ...
        pass
```

Comment: yeah I know that. But in my case the problem is that each model that has his own representation in database, initially inherits from `AbstractModel` which actually is abstract, so he doesn't have database representation. It's only a template for some certain behaviour of each model. Hope that is clarify a bit...